# Filtering data in R (complex)

Tags: r, dataset, filtering

I have a dataset with 7 million records.

I need to filter the data to only show about 9000 of these.

The first field `dmg` is effectively the primary key and take the format 1-Apr-123456. There are about 12 occurrences of each `dmg` value.

Another column is `O_Y` and takes the value of 0 or 1. It is most often 0, but 1 on about 900 occasions.

I would like to return all the rows with the same `dmg` value, where at least one of those records has and `O_Y` value of 1.

Comment: Can you read the data into R (RAM)? If not, package `sqldf` could be up to the task.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) in order to learn how to make a good question

Comment: Like this? Assume `0_Y` is the j-th column.  `foo<-readLines(datafile,n=1); if foo[j]==1 my.data<-rbind(my.data,foo)` , and loop on that for as many records as you have.

Comment: Roman, thanks - yes, it can read in ok to R. Takes a few minutes but is ok.

Comment: Thanks, Carl, I'll have a go at that,and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thanks, Jiber, I'll try to add more data next time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `data.table` for doing this (`fread` in data.table will be quite handy in reading in the large data set too as you say you have enough RAM).

I am not sure that the following is the best way to do this in data.table but, at least, it should get you started. Hopefully, someone else will come along and list the most idiomatic data.table way for this. But this is what I can think of right now:

Assuming your data.table is called `DT` and has two columns `dmg` and `O_Y`. Use `O_Y` as the index key for `DT` and subset `DT` for `O_Y == 1` (`DT[.(1)]` in data.table syntax). Now find the corresponding `dmg` values. The `unique` of these `dmg` values is your `keys.with.ones`. All this is succinctly done as follows:

```
setkey(DT, O_Y)
keys.with.ones <- unique(DT[.(1), dmg][["dmg"]])
```

Next, we need to extract rows corresponding to these values of `dmg`. For this we need to change the key for `DT` to `dmg` and extract the rows corresponding to the keys above:

```
setkey(DT, dmg)
DT.filtered <- DT[.(keys.with.ones)]
```

And we are done. :)

Please refer to ?data.table to figure out a better method if possible and let us know.